# I have a duplicate column name error using MySql when trying to deploy Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, shipitjs

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'first_name': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `first_name` varchar(255)
```

This is the error I am receiving when I am trying to deploy my Rails app using ShipIt.

My question is: how do I resolve this error?

I started off my application with the user having an attribute called name, and then split up name into first_name and last_name in the following migration. When I reset my database (rails db:reset) everything works fine. When I drop my database, create it, migrate my changes, and seed manually everything looks dandy. My schema looks like it contains only the data that I want. I am confused. When I query the tables using sql and rails, the columns look fine.

```
 /app/db/migrate/20180507080705_break_up_fullname_in_users.rb:3:in `up'
```

That is where it says the error is caused.

This is the entire migration which seems to cause the error:

```
class BreakUpFullnameInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
  add_column :users, :first_name, :string
  add_column :users, :last_name, :string

  User.all.each do |user|
    fn, ln = name.split(' ', 2)
    user.update(first_name: fn, last_name: ln)
  end

  remove_column :users, :name
 end


  def down
    add_column :users, :name, :string

   User.all.each do |user|
     n = [name.first_name, name.last_name].join(' ')
     user.update(name: n)
   end

    remove_column :users, :first_name
    remove_column :users, :last_name
  end

end
```

And this was the original migration to create the table:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :users do |t|
   t.string :email
   t.string :name
   t.string :username
   t.string :password_digest

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

This is my in my schema file under users:

```
create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "email"
 t.string "username"
 t.string "password_digest"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "first_name"
 t.string "last_name"
 t.boolean "admin", default: false
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa I can't deploy my app until I stop receiving this error, and I don't know how to get rid of it. I am asking for insight as to how I should do that! Any assistance whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It makes no sense.  You're saying in your question that your rake db:migrate is working: 'When I drop my database, create it, migrate my changes, and seed manually everything looks dandy'.  So where is the error?

Comment: @HernanVelasquez when I am attempting to deploy my app using ShipIt! I am still getting this error when trying to deploy, however in my local database everything looks fine.

Comment: Is there any visible error in my Breakupfullname migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because the columns **first_name** and **last_name** already been added/committed to the table in database. And also **name** column from users table is removed.

The migration execution already completed and somehow rails has failed to update migration version in **schema_migrations** table might be due to the code that is updating data to two columns first_name and last_name from name field.

So I would suggest comment the all lines present in **up** method and re deploy the file to the server => run the migrations and start the server.

```
def up
  #add_column :users, :first_name, :string
  #add_column :users, :last_name, :string

  #User.all.each do |user|
   # fn, ln = name.split(' ', 2)
   #user.update(first_name: fn, last_name: ln)
  #end

  #remove_column :users, :name
 end
```